# Only wallpaper, no icons or menus after update

Tags: updates

While away from the UK in Zambia my wife ran the update through package manager and now we have no icons.

We have the wallpaper but cannot do anything!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears ???

Comment: have you tried those methods?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your desktop doesn't load. As a workaround you can try to switch to console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in, and issue these commands:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
sudo reboot
```

I hope it will help you.